# Buildozer doesn't create a correct package for Android device

Tags: buildozer

I believe I have a problem with Buildozer on an Android device, but I don't know how to fix.
I have a Python app that works fine on Ubuntu and Windows 10. \n

When I generate the Android app with the buildozer android debug deploy run command, the app is generated, installed on the device connected to ubuntu but crashes after the initial splash screen.\n

I saw from logcat that the app crashes because it doesn't load a bg1.jpg inserted in the img folder where main.py is located.
The jpg is loaded with a "source: 'img / bg1.jpg'" directive inserted in a kv file.
I repeat: the app on Ubuntu and Windows works fine.\n

If I delete this directive from the kv file, the app on Android does not crash.
In buildozer.spec I entered "source.include_patterns = img / *, audio / *, fonts / *"

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: buildozer.spec (some directives):
source.dir = .
source.include_exts = py,png,jpg,kv,atlas,json, css, ttf, wav
source.include_patterns = img/*,audio/*,fonts/*

galaxy.kv:
...

MainWidget:
<MainWidget>:
    canvas.before:
        Rectangle: 
            size:self.size
            source:'img/bg1.jpg'
logcat:
python  : [WARNING] [Image       ] Unable to load image </data/user/0/org.galaxygame.galaxygame/files/app/img/bg1.jpg>
...
python  :  kivy.lang.builder.BuilderException: Parser: File "/data/user/0/org.galaxygame.galaxygame/files/app/galaxy.kv", line 9:

Answer (score 0):

I used this construction

```
source.include_exts = mp3,so,xml,mo #,so,2,6,2,1,a
```

Noone **mo** file didnt add in project.
Then I print log and saw that was in **exts**.
Theare was ['mp3' , 'so' , 'xml' , 'mo #', ' so', '2'] buildozer ignoring comment in the end of line.